# What is the most efficent way to print arrays in golang

Tags: go, time

I'm new to programming and wanted know more about the built-in functions:

Here is the is the program:

```
func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    fmt.Println(os.Args)

    fmt.Println(time.Since(start))
}
```

And its output:

`[A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P] 124.009µs`

Here is my for loop:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"os"
"time"
)

func main() {
start := time.Now()

    var s string
    for i:=0; i<len(os.Args); i++{
        s += os.Args[i] + " " 
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
    
    fmt.Println(time.Since(start))

}
```

with the following output:

`/tmp/go-build994847456/b001/exe/main A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P  25.71µs`

I was expecting to have the built in function in the standard library to be faster.

Do slices make my code less efficient ?

Should I use for loops or standard library `fmt.println`?

I'm also confused how would the `strings.Join(os.Args\[1:\], " ")`  performed 74.293µs

Comment: `time.Now`, as in how much real time has passed, is not a good choice for benchmarking. It can be affected by other things running on the system. And you're doing far too few iterations of a very, very fast operation; you need to do many iterations to get a good read. Use [`testing.Benchmarks`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#hdr-Benchmarks). Also your first program never uses `s`, so it's unclear what you're comparing.

Comment: "I was expecting to have the built in function in the standard library to be faster." - why? A more-specific implementation is generally faster than a more-generic one to accomplish the same thing, the stdlib implementation is as generic as possible by nature.

Comment: Thank you @Schwern for telling me about the testing.Benchmarks and how few iterations doesn't tell anything about efficiency. it's precious information to me. after using it, I found strings.Join(ARRAY, " ") the most efficient. Sorry for presenting the question ambiguously

Comment: Use https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Builder to avoid allocations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use benchmarks:

```
var slice = []string{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P"}

func BenchmarkFMT(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = fmt.Sprint(slice)
    }
}

func BenchmarkStringConcat(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        var str string
        for _, s := range slice {
            str += s + " "
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkStringsBuilder(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        var l int
        for _, s := range slice {
            l += len(s)
        }
        var sb strings.Builder
        sb.Grow(l + len(slice)*len(" "))
        for _, s := range slice {
            sb.WriteString(s)
            sb.WriteString(" ")
        }
        _ = sb.String()
    }
}

func BenchmarkStringsJoin(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = strings.Join(slice, " ")
    }
}
```

```
BenchmarkFMT
BenchmarkFMT-8                    734088          1633 ns/op         616 B/op         34 allocs/op
BenchmarkStringConcat
BenchmarkStringConcat-8          1290666           919.1 ns/op      1200 B/op         32 allocs/op
BenchmarkStringsBuilder
BenchmarkStringsBuilder-8        6074888           198.6 ns/op        64 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkStringsJoin
BenchmarkStringsJoin-8           4941542           241.7 ns/op        64 B/op          1 allocs/op
PASS
```